# Nodejs Express MySQL Session store

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, express

I've been using [connect-mysql-session](https://github.com/CarnegieLearning/connect-mysql-session.git) for storing sessions in a `MySQL` db, but it's not being maintained anymore and have not been updated for 2 years.

Are there any other **mysql session store modules** for **express** that's being actively maintained?

And if not, could i still use `MySQL` db for storing user information etc and use another kind of db to store the session? Like `Redis` or `MongoDB`? Is this good practice?

Comment: https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql Maybe this one

Comment: That's not a session store module but node.js bindings to mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect-session DB extension plugin is simple piece of software and only maintenance needed is usually related to maintain compatibility with DB driver and update dependencies in `package.json`. So it can work for a long time without maintenance.

If you are not comfortable with it, you have several options:

1. There are some forks of the repo on github which are better updated
   (at least dependencies), so you can choose one and use that
   instead of the original, which is not maintained probably any more.
   You can also fork it yourself and update it as you like.
2. You can switch to Redis, Mongo or whatever you like or have to serve
   sessions. It is valid and usual solution to have different DB for
   different purposes, but you get additional technology and you have
   to maintain it.

Answer (score 7):

I was using `connect-mysql-session` for a project I've been working on. After running into a problem with unit/integration testing, I submitted a pull request to its repo. I then noticed all the other pull requests that have gone unanswered (as far back as 2 years!). So, I made my own [mysql session store for express](https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session); should work for connect as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `express-mysql-session` module now. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session